# Uniform continuity of a function: multidimensional distribution function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, uniform-continuity

If a distribution function $F$ defined on $\mathbb{R},$ is continuous then it's uniformly continuous, this is easy to prove, since more generally if $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and has finite limits on $+\infty$ and $-\infty,$ then it's uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}.$

Is it true that continuous multidimensional distribution functions on $\mathbb{R^d},$ $F(x_1,...,x_d)=P(X_1\leq x_1,...,X_d \leq x_d)$ for a vector random variable $(X_1,...,X_d)$?

In other word, if we have a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R},$ having finite limits at $\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}f(x)=l_1,\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} f(x)=l_2$ (meaning that each term is tending to $\infty$), then $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Is there are any references or a proof for this statement?

Comment: Can you please define what you mean in the third paragraph more carefully?

Comment: It means $\lim_{x,y \to +\infty}f(x,y)=l_1$ and that $\lim_{x,y \to -\infty}f(x,y)=l_2$

Comment: What does $\lim_{x,y\to +\infty}f(x,y) = l_1$ mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that for $ F(x_1,\cdots, x_d) =\mathsf{P}(X_1\le x_1,\cdots,X_d\le x_d)$, a multidimensional distribution function of random vector $\mathbf{X}= (X_1,\cdots,X_d) $, if $ F(\mathbf{x})=F(x_1,\cdots, x_d) $ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^d $, the $ F $ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}^d $. To prove it, letting that
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{I}_M(\mathbf{x})&=(I_M(x_1),\cdots,I_M(x_d))\\
&=(x_1\wedge M\vee (-M),\cdots,x_d\wedge M\vee (-M))  
\end{align*}
then $ \mathbf{I}_M(\mathbf{x}) $ is an  $ \mathbb{R}^d \mapsto [-M,M]^d $ continuous map,
\begin{align*}
&\mathbf{I}_M(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{x},\qquad \text{if } \mathbf{x}\in [-M,M]^d,\\
&\|\mathbf{I}_M(\mathbf{x}')-\mathbf{I}_M(\mathbf{x}'')\|
=\max_{1\le i\le d}|I_M(x'_i)-I_M(x''_i)|\\
&\quad\le \|\mathbf{x}'-\mathbf{x}'' \|= \max_{1\le i\le d}|x'_i-x''_i|. \tag{1}
\end{align*}
Also let $F_M(\mathbf{x})=F(\mathbf{I}_M(\mathbf{x}))  $,
then $ F_M=F\circ \mathbf{I}_M  $  (as a composite function
of continuous functions $ F $ and $ \mathbf{I}_M(\mathbf{x})$)
is continuous in $\mathbb{R}^d $ and
\begin{align*}
&F_M(\mathbf{x})=F(\mathbf{x}),\qquad \text{if } \mathbf{x}\in [-M,M]^d,\tag{2}\\
& F \text{ is continous in }\mathbb{R}^d \\
&\implies F \text{ is continous in }[-M,M]^d\\
&\implies F \text{ is uniformly continous in }[-M,M]^d\\
&\implies F_M \text{ is uniformly continous in }[-M,M]^d \quad  (\text{ by (2)})\\
&\implies F_M \text{ is uniformly continous in }\mathbb{R}^d. \quad(\text{by (1))}\tag{3}
\end{align*}
The (3) is derived from following relation
\begin{align*}
&\sup_{\|\mathbf{x}'- \mathbf{x}''\|<\delta}|F_M(\mathbf{x}')-F_M(\mathbf{x}'')|\\
&\quad=\sup_{\|\mathbf{x}'- \mathbf{x}''\|<\delta}|F(\mathbf{I}_M(\mathbf{x}'))
-F(\mathbf{I}_M(\mathbf{x}''))|\\
&\quad 
=\sup_{\|\mathbf{y}'- \mathbf{y}''\|<\delta, \mathbf{y}',\mathbf{y}''\in [-M,M]^d} |F(\mathbf{y}') -F(\mathbf{y}'')| 
\end{align*}
Now we prove the following
\begin{gather*}
|F_M(\mathbf{x})-F(\mathbf{x})|\le \mathsf{P}(\|\mathbf{X}\|\ge M)
\tag{4} 
\end{gather*}
It is clear that
\begin{align*}
\{X_i\le x_i\}&\subset \{X_i\le I_M(x_i)\}\cup \{|X_i|\ge M\}\\
&\subset\{X_i\le I_M(x_i)\}\cup \{\|\mathbf{X}\|\ge M\}\\
\{X_i\le x_i,1\le i\le d\}&\subset \{X_i\le I_M(x_i),1\le i\le d\}\cup\{\|\mathbf{X}\|\ge M\}\\
F(\mathbf{x})&\le F_M(\mathbf{x}) + \mathsf{P}(\|\mathbf{X}\|\ge M).\tag{5}
\end{align*}
Similarly,
\begin{align*}
F_M(\mathbf{x})&= \mathsf{P}(X_i\le I_M(x_i),1\le i\le d)\\
& \le \mathsf{P}(X_i\le x_i, \|\mathbf{X}\|\le M)+\mathsf{P}(\|\mathbf{X}\|\ge M)\\
F_M(\mathbf{x})&\le F(\mathbf{x})+\mathsf{P}(\|\mathbf{X}\|\ge M) \tag{6}
\end{align*}
From (5),(6) we get (4) and
\begin{equation*}
|F(\mathbf{x}'')-F(\mathbf{x}')|\le |F_M(\mathbf{x}'')-F_M(\mathbf{x}')|+2 \mathsf{P}(\|\mathbf{x}\|\ge M)
\end{equation*}

Now for fixed $ M $ letting $ \delta\to0 $ in above expression, using (3) and the uniform continuity of $ F_M $ we have
$$ \varlimsup_{\delta\to0}\sup_{\|\mathbf{x}'-\mathbf{x}''\|\le\delta}|F(\mathbf{x}') -F(\mathbf{x}'')|
\le 2\mathsf{P}(\|X\|\ge M). 
$$
At last, letting $M\to+\infty $, we get
$$ \varlimsup_{\delta\to0}\sup_{\|\mathbf{x}'-\mathbf{x}''\|\le\delta}|F(\mathbf{x}') -F(\mathbf{x}'')| = 0,
$$
and the $ F $ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: You didn't need that the limit should be finite at $+\infty,$ and $-\infty,$ because for $d=1,$ we use it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115949/prove-a-continuous-distribution-function-is-uniformly-continuous#:~:text=Prove%20a%20Continuous%20Distribution%20Function%20is%20Uniformly%20Continuous,-real%2Danalysis%20probability&text=Let%20F%20be%20the%20distribution,over%20the%20entire%20real%20line.&text=If%20%7Cx%E2%88%92y%7C%3E,x%E2%88%92y%7C%3E1.

Comment: $\max_i|x_i'-x_i''|\leq \delta, x_i',x_i''$ should be in $[-M,M]^d,$ right?

Comment: @mathex  $x'_i,x''_i$ may be in $\mathbb{R}^d$, because $F_M$  is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}^d$ too.

Comment: Can you provide a proof for the expression of $F_M,$ in term of $F$, for $d=2,$ and for the general case ?

Comment: @mathex Thank you, there is mistake in above answer, I will rewrite it.

Comment: @mathex, I rewrite it.

Comment: Thank you for correcting it. In $(4),$ I think it should be $||X||,$ right?

Comment: @mathex, Thank you, you are right.

Comment: This way works also to prove that if $F_n \implies F$ and if $F$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^d$ then the convergence also happens uniformly on $\mathbb{R}^d.$ And an easier way to prove that the convergence in term of Levy metric's on $\mathbb{R}^d$ is equivalent to weak convergence: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3606510/l%c3%a9vys-metric-on-mathbbrd

Answer (score 3):

Counterexample: On $\mathbb R^2$ define

$$f(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{1+(y+x)^4}.$$

Let $\epsilon>0.$ Let $M=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt \epsilon}.$ Then for $x,y>M,$

$$\frac{x^2}{1+(y+x)^4} < \frac{x^2}{x^4} =\frac{1}{x^2} <\frac{1}{M^2} =\epsilon.$$

Thus $\lim_{x,y\to \infty} f(x,y)=0.$ Since $f(-x,-y)=f(x,y)$ we have the same result for $x,y\to-\infty.$

However, $f(x,-x) = x^2,$ so $f(x,y)$ is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: $x$ and $y$ should be tending, in the same time to $+\infty$ or to $-\infty$

Comment: "same time" etc. is not a mathematical definition. What is the definition you are using?

Comment: $\forall \epsilon>0,\exists \eta_1,\eta_2>0;\forall x_1 \geq \eta_1,x_2 \geq \eta_2,|f(x_1,x_2)-l_1|\leq \epsilon.$

Comment: OK, thanks, just wanted to be sure. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a following counterexample for the statement. Put $d=2$ and $A=\{(x_1,x_2)\in\Bbb R^2:x_1x_2\ge 0\}\cup \{(n,-n):n\in\Bbb Z\}$. Define a function $f:A\to\Bbb R$ putting $f(x_1,x_2)=0$, if $x_1 x_2\ge 0$, and $f(n,-n)=n^2$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z$. Since $A$ is a closed subset of a metrizable (and, hence, normal) space $\Bbb R^2$, by [Tietze extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem) the function $f$ can be extended to a continuous function on $\Bbb R^2$. Then $$\lim_{x_1,x_2\to +\infty} f(x_1,x_2)= \lim_{x_1,x_2\to -\infty} f(x_1,x_2)=0,$$ but $f$ is not uniformly continuous.